# tcpdf doesn't generate pdf

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file with `tcpdf`. The pdf will contain tables. When I set each `td` to has auto width, the `tcpdf` doesn't generate the file.
First I made all the tables in `html` file, just to be sure that everything works as expected. The problem comes on the second table, which is something like this

```
<style>
  ...
  .table {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }
  ...
</style>
...
<table cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2" scope="col" class="apartment_title">AI</td>
                <td rowspan="2" scope="col" class="apartment_title">Full Name</td>
                <td rowspan="2" scope="col" class="apartment_title">ΟΡΟΦΟΣ</td>
                <td rowspan="2" scope="col" class="apartment_title">ΜΕΤΡΑ</td>
                <td colspan="5" scope="colgroup" class="apartment_title">MM</td>
                <td colspan="5" scope="colgroup" class="apartment_title">Amount</td>
                <td rowspan="2" scope="col" class="apartment_title">Amount 2</td>
                <td rowspan="2" scope="col" class="apartment_title">AI</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">1</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">2</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">3</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">4</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">5</td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">1</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">2</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">3</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">4</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_title">5</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
            </tr>


            <tr class="odd_rows">
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">Some user</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">65.00</td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">47.56</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">180.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">180.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">180.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">180.36</td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">147.56</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">280.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1380.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">40.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">80.36</td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">230.00</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1</td>
            </tr>

            <tr class="odd_rows">
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">Total</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">226.99</td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1000</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1000</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1000</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1000</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">1000</td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">247.56</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">480.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">3380.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">80.36</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">160.36</td>

                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info">460.00</td>
                <td scope="col" class="apartment_info"></td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

I saw the examples, and on each `td` has only fixed width, Is it possible to set auto width or not?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No, the only error was a timeout but I changed the value from php.ini. It just never ends the creation. If I don't set auto width the pdf creation works fine.

Comment: If I may - don't use TCPDF. Instead use `laravel/snappy` by `barryvdh`. Super flexible and it uses the `wkhtmltopdf` library, allowing you to seemlessly convert a Laravel view to a PDF file. You can just write standards compliant HTML 5 and it will render beautifully.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll check it right now